# Python: Conditionals for optional function arguments

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Let's say I have a function that accepts 3 optional arguments:

```
def function(arg1=0, arg2=0, arg3=0)
```

What is the cleanest way to handle conditionals within the function depending on which argument is passed?

Right now all I have is:

```
def function(arg1=0, arg2=0, arg3=0)
    if arg1 !=0 and arg2 !=0 and arg3 != 0:
        # do stuff with all three args
    elif arg1 !=0 and arg2 != 0:
        # do stuff with arg1 and arg2, etc...
```

To expand upon this, what if my function can take 5 arguments? Doing conditionals for all possible combinations seems like a drag. Can I not do something else to check which arguments have been passed to the function?

UPDATE:
Based on some feedback I guess I'll just explain in real terms what I'm doing. I need to estimate someone's age based on when they graduated from school (high school, college, graduate program, etc). I may have multiple years to go on, and in fact I may have multiple years for each of high school, college, etc.

So, an example might be:

```
def approx_age(highSchool=0, college=0):
    this_year = date.today().year
    if (highSchool != 0) and (college != 0):
        hs_age = (this_year - highSchool) + 18
        college_age = (this_year - college) + 21
        age_diff = abs(hs_age - college_age)
        if age_diff == 0:
            return hs_age
        elif return (hs_age + college_age)/2
    elif highSchool != 0:
        hs_age = (this_year - highSchool) + 18
        return hs_age
    elif college != 0:
        college_age = (this_year - college) + 21
        return college_age
```

Things are only going to get more complicated from here...

Comment: You have conditions for all possible combinations, or just the number of arguments passed?

Comment: `arg != 0` is equal to `if arg` in most cases, actually.

Comment: The second `if` clause will be true if the 1st `if` clause is true. Do you want that?

Comment: `*args` and `**kwargs` are the way to go.

Comment: @Sriram Sorry, I updated to change the second conditional to an elif. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

why to check the argumnet with value `0` and use of `elif` is pythonic.
conditional statement check statement `Truth value` if it is True then condition proceed else switch for next condition.

and

```
In [112]: bool(0)
Out[112]: False

In [113]: bool(None)
Out[113]: False
```

so if argument value is `0` you don't need to match it with `0` python selfly illustrate it.

```
def function(arg1=0, arg2=0, arg3=0)
    if arg1 and arg2 and arg3:
        # do stuff with all three args

    elif arg1 and arg2:
        # do stuff with arg1 and arg2, etc...
    ..
    ..

    else:
        #do something
```

or for `None` too:

```
def function(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None)
        if arg1 and arg2 and arg3:
            # do stuff with all three args
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please see my addition to the OP regarding what to do if there are many potential arguments?

Comment: @AutomaticStatic 'Can I not do something else to check which arguments have been passed to the function?' i didn't get it mean what you want to do here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can boil it down to this using basic math

```
def function(arg1=0, arg2=0, arg3=0):
    if arg1 * arg2 * arg3 != 0:
        # do stuff with all three args
    if arg1 * arg2 != 0:
        # do stuff with arg1 and arg2, etc...
```

Comment: That would work only if args will stay integers, tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None)
    if (arg1 and arg2 and arg3):
        # do stuff with all three args
    if (arg1 and arg2):
        # do stuff with arg1 and arg2, etc...
```

I think `None` would work better in your case.

```
>>> if (1 and 1 and 1):
...     print True
... 
True
>>> if (0 and 0 and 0):
...     print True
...
... 
>>> if (None and None and None):
...     print True
...
```

So it you will get all 3 args in first condition then only it will get inside of your `if scope`.

Same for case second it will get inside of if scope if both arg1 and arg2 are not `None` or `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain since I don't know what your function is doing with all these arguments, but it seems like you should use `**kwargs`:

```
def function(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        do_the_thing()
```

The `**` syntax means your function will accept any and all keyword arguments, and stick them in a dict. `kwargs` is a common name to give that dict. You can also use `*args` to get an array of positional arguments.

Oh also--if you do end up checking truthiness of the arguments, please consider using `all`:

```
if all([arg1, arg2, arg3]):
```

Comment: How this "detects" if two arguments are 0, and which ones, or if 3 arguments are 0, etc?, or only one given, but which?

Comment: It doesn't; it operates on which arguments were actually passed by the caller.

Comment: Yep, and it seems that OP wants to know exactly which arguments were passed, if they are 0 or not, and do some some stuff depending on this.

Comment: It could be. I was reading those 0s as sigils for "no value was passed for this argument."